# Flexible width for tooltip on hover with position absolute

Tags: html, css

Below is my basic code. (`.iconWrap` in hidden in real scenario. It visible on hover of `li`. Not added the hover code.)

Need to have `.iconWrap` to be of flexible width. So that it can adjust its width according to number of icons inside it. Currently I have given   `width: 150px;` to `.iconWrap`

If you remove `width: 150px;` icons fall one below another. What I want is

1. If there are is one icons width should be only that much to fit one icon and increase according to the number of icons.
2. If there are more than 5 icons 6th icon should fall below the first icon.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.nav {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.iconWrap {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  right: 0;
}

.iconWrap a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.iconWrap a i {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="iconWrap">
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.iconWrap{white-space:nowrap}`

Comment: white-space:nowrap fails for the second condition of 6th icon should fall below 1st

Comment: @dipikapatil this condition is satisfy in my answer. you can check it.

Comment: @ankitapatel Thanks this helped. But now the issue is .iconWrap has left : auto and right: 0 which get position relative to UL

Comment: @dipikapatil can you provide any screenshot how do you want..?

Comment: @ankitapatel I have updated the code. It should be right aligned. Your solution works when it is left aligned.

Comment: @dipikapatil I have updated my code. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;` property into `.iconWrap`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.iconWrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 120px;
}

.iconWrap a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.iconWrap a i {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="iconWrap">
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This dose not work. It fails for second condition "6th icon should fall below 1st icon"

Comment: Now the 1st conditions fails. you can't achieve this with width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.iconWrap {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.iconWrap a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.iconWrap a i {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000
}
/****right-menu**/
.right-menu{
  margin-top:50px;
}
.right-menu .nav{
  text-align:right;
}
.right-menu .iconWrap {  
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="iconWrap">
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- right-align menu -->
<div class="wrap right-menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="iconWrap">
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well for 1nd condition but fails for 2nd. 6th icon should fall below 1st icons.

Comment: No, it's not fall down. I have checked it. You can check in my snippet code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-width` `iconWrap` on  `max-width:120px` change `position` to `.nav` remove to `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.nav{
position: relative;}
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.iconWrap {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
max-width: 120px;
  
}

.iconWrap a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.iconWrap a i {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="iconWrap">
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display flex will do, just add two lines into your CSS as follows:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.nav {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.iconWrap {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex; /* added */
  width: 145px; /* added */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* added */
  right: 0;
}

.iconWrap a {
  margin: 2px; /* added */
  display: inline-block;
}

.iconWrap a i {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="iconWrap">
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i></i></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well for 1nd condition but fails for 2nd. 6th icon should fall below 1st icons

Comment: @dipikapatil you probably will need to fix the height and set `flex-wrap: wrap` in the container where `display: flex` property is written.

Comment: @dipikapatil [Click here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn more about flexbox

Comment: @dipikapatil [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) if you want to learn it really and having time, Flexbox is really handy for so many use cases so better learn it as much as you can.

Comment: It dose not adjust width when icons less than 4.

Comment: @dipikapatil [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/devsumanmdn/pen/NBjObM?editors=1100) , `nav>li { display: inline-block }` is preventing it from being having a adjustible width.